# Can I create a C# object containing a form's controls and their properties?

Tags: c#, object, desktop

I'm currently working on a Windows Forms application in C#.  At the moment, I have four forms that have multiple controls of a variety of different types (textboxes, datagrids, labels etc) and I wanted to separate my project out so that the only code that sits behind each form is the code that's placed there by Visual Studio, so the event methods and so forth.  Any code that I write myself would be in a separate class which would be referenced from the form itself.

I've managed to do it, but of course have found that every method in that separate class needs to include a parameter for each control being manipulated.  Therefore, I wondered if it was possible to build up an object which would contain the properties of every control on the form.  That way, when I'm calling those separate class methods, I simply need to pass the control object to that external class, and would then be able to reference whichever controls I needed and manipulate them.

As an example, my starting form (which has very little code behind it that wasn't put there by the compiler), I have the Form Load event, which looks like this:

```
    private void fFinancialStuff_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cust.LoadForm(this);
    }
```

Then in the external class, the method being referenced above looks like this:

```
    public void LoadForm(Form frm)
    {

        int MonitorCount = SystemInformation.MonitorCount;
        _ = Screen.AllScreens[MonitorCount - 1].WorkingArea;
        var location = Screen.AllScreens[MonitorCount - 1].WorkingArea.Location;

        location.Offset((Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Width - frm.Width) / 2, (Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Height - frm.Height) / 2);

        frm.Location = location;

        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        frm.Text = Prog.glbStr.ApplicationName + " version " + Prog.glbStr.ApplicationVersion;
        frm.Refresh();

    }
```

This is obviously a fairly simple example, but a lot of the methods I've written subsequently have been set up to pass upwards of 20 parameters.  If I could figure out a means of defining an object which would contain all of the form's controls and their properties (and instantiate it each time the method called upon it) it would reduce the amount of code being needed and would also mean that if I wanted to reference a previously-unreferenced control, I wouldn't need to change the method signatures.

Comment: Are you aware of `partial` classes? If all you're trying to do is split code up across multiple files and isolate, say, designer-generated code from "user" code, then it's a perfect use-case for a `partial` class.

Comment: This kind of procedural programming isn't the Winforms way, its designed to support object-oriented programming strongly.  Derive your own class from Form and override the OnLoad() method.  This applies to controls as well.

Comment: You are trying to delegate the process of changing state of the form to an object which doesn't have any knowledge of the form. Ideally everything else than state change should be delegated.

Comment: Daniel Mann, I'm not aware of Partial classes, if I'm being honest.  Most of my C# knowledge was self-taught when I came over from VB.NET.  But yes, all I'm trying to do is separate designer-generated code from user-generated code.  Can you give me some resources that would help me to understand Partial classes?